# Firebase insertion overwites instead of appending

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this database structure in firebase:
[image: Firebase database]
Its supposed to collect votes. I have several categories such as president, minister...etc. All people who vie for a "President" seat are listed using their unique keys, and Im trying to collect all voters emails. 
This is my code:

```
public static void insertvote(String userkey, String categ, String candId) {
       System.out.println("Returned candidate's userkey or ID: "+userkey);
      System.out.println("Returned category: "+categ);
            DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            DatabaseReference totalVotesRef = rootRef.child("votes").child(categ).child(candId);
            Vote vote = new Vote(userkey);
            totalVotesRef.setValue(vote.getVoterEmail());
    }
```

The problem I have is that, when another user logs in and votes, instead of appending their email, its being overwritter to the existing email.
How can I resolve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `setValue()` at the location to collect emails, which always overwrites existing data, you should look into using [`push()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#push()) first, which generates a new child using a random ID.  You will want to become familiar with the documentation on working with lists of data, especially [appending to a list of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data).

```
totalVotesRef.push().setValue(vote.getVoterEmail())
```

Each email will appear under that randomly generated child value.

Comment: Not in a way that scales well. This is the preferred approach, unless you want to read and write an attay each time.

Comment: Is there a way to ensure that the email address does not get added twice? In the above case, ensure that hr@gmail.com only exists once inside the list? –

Comment: If you have a new problem to solve, please post it separately.